# How do I convert a string with 'hashtags' to json in java?

Tags: java, json

I have a String in java that might look like this:

```
String str = "Hello this is #David's first comment #excited"
```

I want to convert this string to a json object, but it throws an error when I use the below:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
```

I have found out that it throws an error due to the '#' symbol.
Is there any other way to convert the string to json, without much hassle ?

Comment: Have you tried a JSON parsing library such as Jackson or Gson?

Comment: Please identify the attributes and values from your sample string (because your string looks nothing like json and there's nothing to indicate how to interpret it)

Comment: @DanW : Gson does not allow you to convert a string to JSON, it allows only an entity to be converted to string.

Comment: @sagarvikani No - gson converts both ways: json --> object and object --> json. Also, you seem a little confused: "json" *is* a String (just like XML and CSV are Strings)

Comment: @Bohemian except, there are only two valid forms of a JSON string: `["a string"]` and `{"key":"a string"}`. Given the example provided, what is the key for the new `JSONObject` object?

Comment: Ok so here's the deal, I have a string which looks like this String commentStr = {subjectCategory:"s123", subjectId:"111222333", content:"test comment111", ownerId:"111", ownerName:"tester"} And I want it to be something like this : {"subjectCategory":"s123","subjectId":"111222333","content":"test comment111","ownerId":"111","ownerName":"tester"} So right now what I do is: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(commentStr); which works fine for all strings, except when I add '#' in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not so much the '#' symbols; it's that you are trying to parse the string as if it's already JSON. You probably want something like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("firstString", str);
String jsonString = json.toString();
```

or, more briefly (if all you want is a quoted JSON string:

```
String jsonString = JSONObject.valueToString(str);
```

Comment: Ok so here's the deal, I have a string which looks like this 

String commentStr = {subjectCategory:"s123", subjectId:"111222333", content:"test comment111", ownerId:"111", ownerName:"tester"}

And I want it to be something like this :
{"subjectCategory":"s123","subjectId":"111222333","content":"test comment111","ownerId":"111","ownerName":"tester"}

So right now what I do is:

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(commentStr);

which works fine for all strings, except when I add '#' in the string

Comment: @sagarvikani - That's very odd. The '#' character is not one of the reserved characters according to the [JSON spec](http://json.org/). Be that as it may, perhaps you can work around this by replacing "#" in the string with "\u0023" (the JSON Unicode escape sequence for '#'). By the way, what's the exception being thrown?

Comment: json.JSONException: Unterminated string at 63 [character 64 line 1]

I found a solution on a post here, which says the same thing. I will have to convert the # to it's hexadecimal code. I wish there was a simpler way to do it.

Comment: I got a similar issue, but it finally has nothing to do with the JSON parser. It was a custom parser which split a String into parts with a `#` character as a separator.