# Escape number sign (hash tag) in java when parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm writing an Android app where I'm trying to get the #text string from a JSON that looks like this

```
{
"recenttracks": {
  "track": {
    "artist": {
      "#text": "Jeremy Fisher",
      "mbid": "7be30286-3510-4bc4-a587-51d9ad7c2b47"
 ...
```

But because of the hash tag I get nothing in return:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for
```

Replacing #text with mbid works fine. Code:

```
try{
JSONObject container = new JSONObject(readLastFMFeed);
JSONObject recenttracks = container.getJSONObject("recenttracks");   
JSONObject track = recenttracks.getJSONObject("track");   
JSONObject artist = track.getJSONObject("artist");   
String sArtist = track.getString("#text");
Toast.makeText(LoggedIn.this, sArtist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }catch(JSONException e){
          Log.e("log_tag", " Error parsing data "+e.toString());
     }
```

How can I escape the hash tag?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling getString on artist, not on track?

Comment: I found this related question, which may help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788664/how-do-i-convert-a-string-with-hashtags-to-json-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape it. You just made a little silly mistake. Instead of:

```
String sArtist = track.getString("#text");
```

Write:

```
String sArtist = artist.getString("#text");
```

Comment: Duuh. I actually noticed it a second before I saw your comment ;) Thank you, it's working fine now.